# TextWatcher working late

Tags: android, textwatcher

My textwatcher is working after I press backspace and then that suggestion comes. 
I have a textwatcher that generates a list of books from web. I also waited to see whether its a net issue. But I found its not because of that, when I press backspace it start working smoothly.Please help

```
textWatcher = new TextWatcher() 
    {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
        {
             chars = s;
             currentSearch = s;
             startSuggestionsThread(s); 
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
        }
    };
```

I startsuggestionsthread I am doing textview.setAdapter(adapter). But its taking much time

Comment: textview instanceOf ListView ?

Comment: No its just a normal Autocomplete text view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are using your logic inside `afterTextChanged` method of **TextWatcher**. Move your code to `beforeTextChanged` in order to run your code before the text is changed in **EditText**

Comment: I shifted the code to aftertextchanged and it worked. Bu its working too slowly.

Comment: The log before textview.setAdapter(adapter) is working.But the data on the adapter is displayed very late.

Comment: If you are fetching data from internet, then you are on the mercy of your connection speed. There's no other way than meanwhile showing a progress-bar to inform user that the data is being downloaded.